# verb for describing the motion of the hairs on the back of the neck of a horse

Tags: word-request, verbs

When a horse is running, if the hairs on the back of their neck are long, they "float" in the air.

What is the better word for "float"? I cannot think of any, and I cannot find a suitable search string on the net.

I have in mind also "flutter", "wave", but they seem equally bad.

Does the same verb apply to the movement of the tail hairs, as well the hairs of a person with long hair?

Side question: does the same verb apply to a flag in the wind?

Comment: Those hairs are the horse's **mane**. We speak of a _flying mane_.

Comment: A flag is said to be flying when it has been hoisted on a flagpole. If it's visibly moving in the wind, it could be described as fluttering. _Waving_ is mainly what you do with a flag you are holding in your hand.

Comment: So the flag which is just hanging on the flagpole, with no wind and no movement, is still "flying"?

Comment: @virolino For a person to “fly” a flag means to put it up on a flagpole, regardless of the wind. The flag itself is only flying if there is wind. Only the latter sense would apply to a mane.

Answer (score 1):

The "hairs on the back of a horse's neck" are called its **mane**.

Looking for "mane VERB" in the iWeb corpus, the only word that comes up with this meaning is *mane flowing*.